# Windows Vista stuck on crcdisk.sys

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, boot

I'm here with some Vista-trouble. After a cigarette-break I returned to my desk to find my PC with a black screen, and after failing to wake it up did a forced restart. I haven't been installing any hardware or software for quite a while.

Ever since, Vista gets stuck on the animated 'Microsoft Corporation' progress bar with the animation still running and no hard disk activity. With an F8 and safe-mode + prompt I saw that the boot gets stuck at `crcdisk.sys`.

I'm running Vista64 SP1.

What could the problem be? Any advice?

Comment: Microsoft is trying to get you to quit smoking?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known and annoying issue. Unfortunately the solution isn't clear cut.

Basically, a couple of system files aren't passing their file integrity check on boot. This could be caused by any number of things:

1. Ram errors (This is what mine was. Replaced the RAM, problem vanished)
2. Hard Drive errors (Try running chkdsk /f a couple of times. Make sure it finishes cleanly twice.)
3. Bad storage driver. Might be able to go to "last known good config" and fix it.

This one is trial and error. You're going to have to try a number of things.

Comment: I received this error on a XPS M1330; running the built-in diagnostics (press F12 at boot) identified the problem as a hard drive failure. I was able to recover most files by mounting the drive in a different computer.